# Connecting to localhost/index.php through my smart phone

Tags: php, wifi, localhost

I want to connect to my localhost using my smart phone through WiFi.

I got my IP via [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com), and got my smart phone to connect to my laptop successfully.

However, when I type `localhost` as the web address in the browser of my phone, nothing shows up.

How can I access `localhost/index.php` page through my smart phone?

Comment: "localhost" on your smart phone is your smart phone.

Comment: Can you able to post your code, that you have tried so for ??

Comment: there is no code. It is a technology question :)

Comment: To stop getting downvotes on the questions you post here at SO, go through FAQ's (most importantly, what to ask here, how to ask a question).

Comment: you can try using `http://[ip of your laptop]/index.php` also in wamp server make it `online`.

Comment: You might be better off using the domain name.  usually (computer_name).local for Linux and Mac systems.

Answer (score 1):

use your laptop  wifi connection  ip instead of localhost like 192.168.50.2.

Comment: Dont put MINUSES to my topic!

Why do you put minuses instead of helping and answering to my question??? 

I cant understand! Do you really hate learning programmers????

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your pc and phone in the same lan？

Your phone can access first， because you use public network ip.
I guess you can not access by using localhost ip, because they are not in the same lan.

Answer (score 0):

1) Install a proxy server on your laptop (for example [FreeProxy](http://www.handcraftedsoftware.org/index.php?page=download&op=getFile&id=2&title=FreeProxy-Internet-Suite)) don't run it yet!

2) Get the local ip of your laptop (the one used inside your network, given by your wifi router) by running Start -> cmd -> ipconfig.

Look for a line like: `Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection`
And under it you need the value from `IPv4 Address`.
The IP should be something like: 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x
Copy this IP address, you will need it for the next step.

2) Edit the hosts file on your laptop (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts), you will need administrator permissions to edit this file. add a line into this file like:

10.0.0.1  laptop

Now, the 10.0.0.1 should be replaced by the local IP of your laptop (obtained at step #2).
Save the file.

3) Run the proxy server.

4) Configure your smarphone to use the proxy server (this is smartphone specific, which one do you have?).

5) In your smartphone browser type the address: http://laptop/index.php

Comment: you dont have permission to access ----> it says

Comment: You don't have permission to access what? if you get this while editing the hosts file, you need to run Notepad or the editor you are using ad an administrator for example: Start -> type notepad -> right click the notepad link in the search results -> Run as administrator.

Comment: I dont have permission to access my localhost.

Comment: Evrth is ok. But in browser, while I am writing that adress, it says I dont have permission to access that page

Comment: by the way, my IPv4 Address is different, it is : 169.254.128.216

Comment: What happens if in your smartphone browser your type: `http://169.254.128.216/index.php`

Comment: can you give your yahoo id? I can explain you there my problem

Comment: I've created a chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10360/smarphone-access-to-pc please join

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to upload your source to a server that accessible through the internet and get the hosts ip address and try to load it on the smart phone.

If you want to access your app from your laptop you need to figure out what is your ip on your laptop then access your localhost.

```
 On windows run: ipconfig /all (get ip)

 On linux run: sudo / ip -addr (get ip)
```

Make sure you stay connected to the wifi on your smartphone.

Comment: also make sure apache or your webserver is on (up and running)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this question was asked more than 2 years ago. Thanks anyway