# Acess localhost site using a smartphone without WIFI

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, localhost

I am trying to run my localhost website in my Lumia 520. I have a laptop with MTS Ultra Blaze and my laptop has no wifi features. Is it possible to run a localhost website in my Lumia520...

thanks

Comment: i dont know, but i do it when ever i want with the laptop, but it wont be live. you can check weather your code is working or not. Thanks

Comment: is there anyway without wifi??

Comment: to go live with website, or to just check the code??

Comment: to go live with website

Comment: in my view no you cant do that,  but even you have wifi, dont go live with the website, from your laptop, you gonna cry a river. sooner or later, probably sooner. and i am serious. its too risky. Its like jumping in lake, full of crocodile they definetly going to eat you

Comment: if you too desprate. some webhost give you free hosting for month, google it. Than you will know it worth paying for it or not. but they are hard to find

Comment: by the way this is what i am trying to ask but wthout wifi ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265967/connecting-to-localhost-index-php-through-my-smart-phone

Comment: if thats what you want to do. you need a internate connection And wifi is internate connection in short you can do it with any internate connection. I never though about it so i dont know how to do it. . But i know you can go live if you have internate connection. google it. and google the free webhost provider. As if some thing blow up tommorow you are safe.

Comment: sorry just check spelling mistake in last comment, in short you can do it with any internate connection, WIFI is not necessary. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you actually can access localhost through USB/Bluetooth tethering if your phone is supporting this feature.